# How do I redirect the Debug output in Visual Studio 2019 to a file?

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to redirect the Debug output in Visual Studio 2019 to a file?

[image] I am a java dev and not very familiar with C#/ Visual studio. I want to read the Debug output in some external editor like vim.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With the Output window active, you can go to File - Save as... and save it to a file.

Comment: Nice. I am looking for an automatic way where VS is writing to the file itself.